# In Regex after match use group method to return only a part of the string

Tags: python, regex, group

I am using the regular expression below to get the names of 40 hotels from a HTML file using python using grouping.

[edit]- The catch is that we have to do this only using Regex and no other module like Beautiful Soup

```
pattern_names = re.compile(r'\t(?P<Hotel_name>[a-zA-Z0-9][a-z0-9]*.+)\n</a>\n')
name_list=pattern_names.findall(data)
print("No of hotels=",len(name_list))
name_list
```

I am getting the required list of 40 names, but some of these names are having "& amp;" string due to presence of "&" in the HTML file.

```
"Rocco's Cafe",
 'Local Kitchen &amp; Wine Merchant',
 'Ristorante Umbria',
 'flour + water',
 'Firewood At Metreon',
 'Palomino',
 'Buono',
 'Farina Focaccia &amp; Cucina Italiana',
```

I want to modify my regular expression so that "& amp;" is not returned with the string name.

I tried the following regex

`pattern_names = re.compile(r'\t(?P<Hotel_name>[a-zA-Z0-9][a-z0-9]*.+^[&amp;])\n</a>\n')`

but this returned an empty list. No strings matched.

Answer (score 0):

There

```
pattern_names = re.compile(r'\t(?P<Hotel_name>[a-zA-Z0-9][a-z0-9]*.+^[&amp;])\n</a>\n')
```

you have `^` *inside* which does not make sense for `^` which denotes begin of line, also observe that `[&amp;]` means one of characters listed, i.e. `&` or `a` or `m` or `p` or `;`.

I suggest to properly process text from HTML rather than deleting HTML entities, [`html.unescape`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) (part of standard library) allows you to do it easily

```
import html
names = ['Local Kitchen &amp; Wine Merchant','Firewood At Metreon','Farina Focaccia &amp; Cucina Italiana']
cleaned_names = [html.unescape(i) for i in names]
print(cleaned_names)
```

output

```
['Local Kitchen & Wine Merchant', 'Firewood At Metreon', 'Farina Focaccia & Cucina Italiana']
```

Comment: @Daewo - Thank you for the reply. The catch is that we have to do this only using Regex and no other module like Beautiful Soup/html. I was able to use re.sub() for making the corrections, but I wanted an elegant solution using the regular expression itself.